# Why does atrazine kill photosynthetic bacteria and not nonphotosynthetic bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, photosynthesis, bioenergetics, herbicide

Atrazine was found to bind to Qb, which is involved in electron transport to create ATP in photosynthetic bacteria.

Why does this herbicide kill photosynthetic bacteria, while having little to no effect in nonphotosynthetic?

- Is this possibly just because electron cycling creates energy in photosynthetic, and non-photosynthetic heterotrophs use a different mechanism to create ATP?